# How can the new "Pokemon Catching" activity type be used in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

The latest update of [Google Maps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps&hl=en) includes a Pokemon catching activity type as described on the update page of the app:

> Add “catching Pokémon” as an activity type in your Timeline to
>   remember the times and places you caught them

I've just updated the app but can't find the related activity type in it. Did anyone try it out and found how to use it?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Thanks for the tag. It's much better this way.

Answer (score 1):

From [this article :](http://bgr.com/2016/09/05/google-maps-update-pokemon-go/)

> What you have to do to access it is to go to “Your timeline” inside the app, tap on the travel icon and edit it to “catching Pokemon."

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think it's being swarmed right now because the Timeline feature can't be accessed at the moment. Btw I wasn't expecting anything from Google Maps. I'm not even playing Pokemon Go (yet). I was just curious about what Google did to incorporate a feature for a popular mobile game and inform players about it so others could use it and hopefully report us back about its merits.

Comment: Yeah it looks like it's just a fun addition that doesn't actually tie into Pokemon go. Even looking at what the update did confused me a bit, since Pokemon Go (at least at one point) used Google's API for mapping.